# I want to connect to MySQL Database on my website on Namecheap

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, namecheap

**with this code I connect to MySql in local with xampp successfully, but I can't connect to myDatabase in my website with cPanel -> phpMyAdmin . maybe I didn't ask the right question, But I hope someone understands my question and can help me. here is my code: **

```
private void SourceServerConnMySql()
{
    string server = TxBxSourceServer.Text;
    string userName = TxBxSourceUserName.Text;
    string pass = TxBxSourcePassword.Password;
    string port = TxBxSourcePort.Text;
    string connectionString = "host='" + server + "'; user='" + userName + "'; Password='" + pass + "'; port= '"+ port +"' ; Connection Timeout=30;";
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            ImageRightGif.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            successTextBlock.Text = "Database has been successfully connected and fetched.";
            SuccessDelay();
            ErrorTextBlock.Text = "";
            ImageErrorGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            infoTextBlock.Text = "";
            ImageInfoGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            //StackPanelDB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            string query = "show databases;";
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            CoBoxDB.Items.Clear();
            CoBoxDB.Items.Add("Select a Database . . .");
            ProgressBar();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string databases = dr.GetString(0);
                CoBoxDB.Items.Add(databases);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ImageErrorGif.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ErrorTextBlock.Text = "Could not connect to the database.";
            ErrorDelay();
            successTextBlock.Text = "";
            ImageRightGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            infoTextBlock.Text = "";
            ImageInfoGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ImageErrorGif.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ErrorTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
        ErrorDelay();
        successTextBlock.Text = "";
        ImageRightGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        infoTextBlock.Text = "";
        ImageInfoGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

**and here is the interface for my app:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncn6p.jpg)**

Comment: by the way, I tried to write in Server Text box my domain name www.example.com and IP for Website too. And in User name and password I entered my database login data .
But it still doesn't working

Comment: The link is using the filenames of the database to copy to target server.  See following for the filenames of the MYSQL database.  You may not have the permissions in windows to perform the copy : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-database-files/

Comment: Side note: you need to dispose the connection, command and reader objects with `using`

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your comment, but can you please more explain? I couldn't understand anything from the attached link.

Comment: @Charlieface I made it as you said, as following:

Comment: `try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                       //some code
                        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                        {
                            using (MySqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                            }`

Comment: A server can contain more than one database.  You need to select which database you are copying.  The database can be attached to a server of just be a file.  The tool gives you are option to use either a attached database to server or a file.  Each database on the server has a different file.

Comment: @jdweng with this Funktion I just want to show the whole databases on the server. But copy databases there is another Funktion.
As you see in photo of interface , when I click the button 'get databases from server', it will show databases.

Comment: copy existing database to the new server using the tool.

Comment: @jdweng that is exactly the Target of my tool , copy databases from a server to another.